# TextMate, Cucumber & Spork: Run feature **with** HTML output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, textmate, spork

I use Cucumber to test my Rails app, and thanks to a running Spork I don't have to start the whole Rails app every time I run a scenario.

I have set the `TM_CUCUMBER_OPTS` to `--drb` within TextMate, which works fine, but it results in awkward formatting of the results: it's only text, not HTML anymore.

Any way to fix that? I tried --format=html, but this results in:

```
Running: /Users/josh/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/script/cucumber 
/Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/features/authorization/sign_out.feature --drb --format=html
    Using the default profile...
    Disabling profiles...
    Exception encountered: #<RuntimeError: All but one formatter must use --out, only one can print to each stream (or STDOUT)>
    backtrace:
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:198:in `arrange_formats'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:26:in `parse!'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:55:in `configuration'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:63:in `run_drb_client'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework/cucumber.rb:24:in `run_tests'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@iq/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
    /Users/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from Jim Drannbauer worked for me: http://jimdrannbauer.com/2011/02/22/cucumber-spork-textmate-drb-drbunknown/